# Rails 3.2 and activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

Just make and upgrade to rails 3.2 from 3.1.3.

The activeadmin is not getting work else is fine so far... its not ladading css files and showing this exception in admin.css file

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon.
              Load paths:
                /home/gull/Desktop/projects/avm_web_services/public/stylesheets/sass
                /home/gull/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/activeadmin-0.4.0/app/assets/stylesheets
                /home/gull/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/activeadmin-0.4.0/lib/active_admin/sass
        on line 11 of /home/gull/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/activeadmin-0.4.0/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_all.css.scss
        from line 1 of /home/gull/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/activeadmin-0.4.0/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_mixins.css.scss
        from line 2 of /home/gull/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/activeadmin-0.4.0/lib/active_admin/sass/active_admin.scss
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

rails generate active_admin:assets

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it like so (application.rb):

https://gist.github.com/1197686

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but [you can make it better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) by including a summary or relevant portions of the pages you're linking to. This will also help your answer remain great even if the links you included break in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same "Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon" problem, but neither

```
rails generate active_admin:assets
```

nor

```
Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
```

solve my problem.

Finally I `bourbon install` in my project and then move all the generated stylesheets/folders to app/assets/stylesheets folder, and it works, so far so good...